# Unity3d Swipe jump is not very responsive

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build and android game using unity3D. This is my character controller script that I wrote. The swipe up part is towards the end of the code I have commented on where it is.

```
float speed = 11.0f;
public float jumpForce = 0.005f;


public float FingerInitialPosition = 0f;
public float FingerMovedPosition = 0f;
public float startTouchPosition = 0f;
public float endTouchPosition = 0f;

public Rigidbody2D rb;
public Vector3 jump;
public int jumpCount;


Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    jump = new Vector3(0.0f, 1f, 0.0f);

}


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{

    Debug.Log("Collided");
    jumpCount=0;            

}

void FixedUpdate()
{

    Debug.Log(jumpCount);
    if(transform.position.y < -14) { SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex); }


    foreach (Touch FingerTouch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (FingerTouch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            if (FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                FingerInitialPosition = FingerTouch.position.x;
            }
            else if (FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                FingerMovedPosition = FingerTouch.position.x;

                if (FingerMovedPosition > FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                     float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                     hval += 19f;
                     hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                     rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);



                }
                else if (FingerMovedPosition < FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                    float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                    hval -= 19f;
                    hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);
                }
            }
            else if (FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                FingerInitialPosition = 0f;
                FingerMovedPosition = 0f;

            }
            else //NEW PART!//
            {
                FingerMovedPosition = FingerTouch.position.x;
                if (FingerMovedPosition > FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                    float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                    hval += 19f;
                    hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);
                }
                else if (FingerMovedPosition < FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                    float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                    hval -= 19f;
                    hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);

                }
            }
        }

        // The part I think needs fixing
        // The swipe Up part where I make the player jump

        if (FingerTouch.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    startTouchPosition = touch.position.y;
                }
                else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    endTouchPosition = touch.position.y;
                    if (endTouchPosition > startTouchPosition)
                    {
                        if (jumpCount<1) {
                            rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                            jumpCount += 1;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }



}
```

Swiping(Horizontal) on the left side of the screen allows the player to move right and left and swiping up on the right side of the screen allows the player to jump my problem is that the jump is not very responsive , I have done a test It was responsive only 3/5 times.

I am also attaching screenshot of my player

[image]

Comment: If you get rid of the `if (jumpCount<1) {` check I understand that it will let you jump infinitely, but does that get rid of the responsiveness problem?

Comment: Also, instead of looping through every touch, do `if  (Input.touchCount >0)` and use `Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);` and see if that helps with responsiveness

Comment: @Ruzihm When I remove the looping part it is not able to detect movement and jumping together and When I remove jumpCount I think it is helping a little but still the controls are not very crisp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a nested loop, continue using the `FingerTouch` item.

Also, instead of doing a comparison when the finger is removed, which can result in delays, just activate whenever it is seen moving up by examining `FingerTouch.deltaPosition.y`:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    Debug.Log(jumpCount);
    if(transform.position.y < -14) { SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex); }


    foreach (Touch FingerTouch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (FingerTouch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
        {
            if (FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                FingerInitialPosition = FingerTouch.position.x;
            }
            else if (FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                FingerMovedPosition = FingerTouch.position.x;

                if (FingerMovedPosition > FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                     float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                     hval += 19f;
                     hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                     rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);



                }
                else if (FingerMovedPosition < FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                    float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                    hval -= 19f;
                    hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);
                }
            }
            else if (FingerTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                FingerInitialPosition = 0f;
                FingerMovedPosition = 0f;

            }
            else //NEW PART!//
            {
                FingerMovedPosition = FingerTouch.position.x;
                if (FingerMovedPosition > FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                    float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                    hval += 19f;
                    hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);
                }
                else if (FingerMovedPosition < FingerInitialPosition)
                {
                    float hval = rb.velocity.x;
                    hval -= 19f;
                    hval *= Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
                    rb.velocity = new Vector2(hval, rb.velocity.y);

                }
            }
        }

        else if (FingerTouch.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
        {
            if (FingerTouch.deltaPosition.y > 0) {
                if (jumpCount<1) {
                    rb.AddForce(jump * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    jumpCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This may only be a partial solution. If this still doesn't work, I'm curious if removing the `if (jumpCount<1)` check makes it work. If it does, the problem would seem to be related to how you set it back to `0`.

Comment: 'Touch' does not contain a definition for 'deltaTouch' and no accessible extension method 'deltaTouch' accepting a first argument of type 'Touch' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I changed the 'deltaTouch' with 'deltaPosition' and the control seems more crisp now

Comment: An unrelated question, My drag right and left script for movement sometimes doesn't respond too like It keeps dragging the player to the right while I swipe and hold towards the left. Can you see any problem in that part too?

Comment: That might be good for another question since there would have to be more questions for you. My first guess is to set `hval = 0;`  when `rb.velocity.x > 0` on `FingerMovedPosition < FingerInitialPosition`. Also do `hval=0;` when `rb.velocity.x < 0` on `FingerMovedPosition > FingerInitialPosition`.

Comment: This will cause the character to instantly move in the opposite direction right?

Comment: @WasimAhmad yes, it will prevent sliding. If you're saying that it's actually changing the velocity in the wrong direction, it might be better to include a check in the horiztonal section like `if ( Mathf.Abs(FingerMovedPosition - FingerInitialPosition) / Screen.width < 0.1f)` (or whatever fraction of the screen should be a dead zone between 0.05f and 0.2f is probably good) then don't make any changes to `rb.velocity`. This will create a dead zone that won't provide any horizontal input.

Comment: well stackoverflow is not allowing me to ask more questions :(

Comment: @Ruzhim  yeah it says "You have reached your question limit"